# Regular expressions issues with zero or more of the character * and substitution

Tags: sed

I am not clear when literature says `*`  means zero or more times the previous character. I want to clarify what does `zero` times the previous character mean?

For example will `a*` match `b` since `b` means `zero occurence of a`. Similarly, will `a*` match the whole line `stckoverflow is gret` or whole file if every line is `stkoverflow is gret`? If so, what is the difference between `a*` and `.*`

Secondly, what is the difference between `s/foo/bar` vs `s/[foo]/bar`? The latter one produces output `baroo`.

Thirdly, what is the difference between  `% echo "123 abc" | sed 's/[0-9]*/& &/'` which outputs
`123 123 abc`

and

`% echo "abc 123" | sed 's/[0-9]*/& &/'` which outputs
`abc 123`

Source for third question: **https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html**

Comment: b is not `zero or more occurrences` of a? a* will match  'a', 'aa', 'aaa', ...

Comment: @Mansoor That is not correct according to Barmer's answer

Comment: @Mansoor Since the regexp isn't anchored, it will match anywhere in the string, so it will match.

Comment: @Barmar please explain anchoring in simple words?

Comment: You may be confusing yourself by saying, "`*`  means zero or more times the previous character." `*` means to repeat the previous *assertion* zero or more times. `a` is the assertion that the next character is an `"a"`, where "next" refers to a location at the beginning of a line or between two consecutive characters. Therefore `a*` asserts that zero or more `"a"`'s follow the current location. Similarly, `[abc]` asserts that the following character is `"a"`, `"b"` or `"c"`, so `[abc]*` asserts the current location is followed by zero or more character, each being `"a"`, `"b"` or `"c"`....

Comment: ....`.*` is the assertion that the current location is followed by a sequence of zero of more characters, each character being any character other than a line terminator. One more: `(?:\d+\D+)*` asserts that the non-capture group `(?:\d\D*)` is asserted zero or more times consecutively, beginning at the current location. (Something like this can be used to assert that a string contained, say, 4 digits: `^\D*(?:\d\D*){4}$`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I could not get when you said next in  `a*` refers to the beginning of line. Can you elaborate that more? Secondly, why this is an assertion?

Comment: The regex engine maintains a pointer in the string it is processing. You can think of the location of that pointer as being at the beginning of the string (I should have said string rather than line), at the end of the string or between two consecutive characters. When I say the "next" or "previous" character it is in reference to the location of that pointer...

Comment: ...As to your second question, a regular expression matches a string if all of its assertions are true. Assertions can be as simple as the next character to being an `"a"` to, for example, the string contains no more than 10 digits or the current location is preceded, from the beginning of the string, by an even number of double-quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `a*` will match `b` and `stckoverlow is gret` because there are zero occurrences of `a` in them. But that's not really a useful case -- you wouldn't normally use `a*` all by itself as a test.

It becomes more useful when it's part of a larger regular expression. For instance `ab*c`. This will match a string containing `ac`, `abc`, `abbc`, etc.

Or you could use the `^` and `$` anchors, which match the beginning and end of the line, respectively. `^a*$` will match a line consisting only of `a`, and will also match an empty line because that contains zero occurrences. But it won't match `b` or `stckoverlow is gret`.

`s/foo/bar/` replaces the string `foo` with the string `bar`. `s/[foo]/bar/` replaces the letter `f` or the letter `o` with `bar`. `[...]` specifies a character set -- it matches a single character that's any of the characters contained within it (if the character set begins with `^` it means any character that's *not* in the rest of the set). Character sets can also contain character ranges `x-y`; e.g. `A-Z` matches any letter, `0-9` matches any digit, `p-t` matches the letters `p`, `q`, `r`, `s`, or `t`, etc.

When you do

```
echo "123 abc" | sed 's/[0-9]*/& &/'
```

the regular expression matches `123` at the beginning of the string, so it replaces it with two copies of it.

When you do

```
echo "abc 123" | sed 's/[0-9]*/& &/'
```

the regular expression matches an empty string at the beginning of the string, because `[0-9]*` will match zero occurrences. It duplicates this empty string in the result.

It always substitutes the first match that it finds on the line. `*` is also "greedy", so it will try to match the longest sequence possible at that point. So in the first example it will match the whole `123` string, not just an empty string.

Comment: I am not clear why `bar` becomes `baroo` since none of the character in `[foo]` match with `bar`? Secondly in  `echo "abc 123" | sed 's/[0-9]*/& &/'` why does `[0-9]` have to match the beginning since there is no `^` sign in front of `[0-9]`

Comment: What is the input that produces `baroo`?

Comment: `s/[foo]/bar` produces `baroo`

Comment: But what was the input line?

Comment: `echo something | sed 's/[foo]/bar/'` what was something?

Comment: Its a file with the following contents . `abc
foo
123 foo show
999 charfoo` Output is `abc baroo 123 foo show 999 charfoo
` Its very strange that `foo` before and after `show` goes unchanged

Comment: the `f` in `foo` matches `[foo]`, so it gets replaced with `bar`, producing `baroo`.

Comment: what about the `foo` that comes after `123` and after `999`

Comment: the fourth comment from the top needs answer about `[0-9]`

Comment: Since you didn't add the `g` modifier, it only replaces the first match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217851/discussion-between-user2979872-and-barmar).